# Cannot connect to AWS Mqtt endpoint inside docker container

Tags: docker, containers, mqtt, aws-iot

I am using the AWS IOT SDK java client to connect to an AWS Mqtt endpoint. If run it locally, it works fine.

Then I wrap up my application inside a docker container and use `docker-compose` to run it, the application just stuck at where it try to make the connection to the endpoing.

However, if I change the docker container's network mode to host:

```
network_mode: "host"
```

It works again.

So I guess there is something wrong with the container network configuration. Do I need to expose any ports specific to the Mqtt (like port 443?) But that does not work as well.

Updated the network setting below:

```
[
{
    "Name": "2234_emulator",
    "Id": "af69dba44fc91922e50c883c80852c0be2d6a87218e5d9821a1331547d39e343",
    "Created": "2022-02-12T14:23:19.298315542Z",
    "Scope": "local",
    "Driver": "bridge",
    "EnableIPv6": false,
    "IPAM": {
        "Driver": "default",
        "Options": null,
        "Config": [
            {
                "Subnet": "172.20.0.0/16"
            }
        ]
    },
    "Internal": false,
    "Attachable": true,
    "Ingress": false,
    "ConfigFrom": {
        "Network": ""
    },
    "ConfigOnly": false,
    "Containers": {
        "0dc64743c4643d972ae5bc9010416880321bb2fde8ad3afd6834fa6d1eaa0cf6": {
            "Name": "2234_ScannerService_1",
            "EndpointID": "1c362f48ec0f4afcd1fe705103c0867fe54d874ddb42f678580edcaf0a23e892",
            "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:14:00:02",
            "IPv4Address": "172.20.0.2/16",
            "IPv6Address": ""
        },
        "5d79cb8e56f7a7789f1860bfc0f48077b326736762c2c13238883bac2a5b40d1": {
            "Name": "2234_DeviceEmulatorService_1",
            "EndpointID": "8f4170c876d527edb22c4ff47ff167d28b86eeb10c78943fdfedd086237c8c26",
            "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:14:00:0f",
            "IPv4Address": "172.20.0.15/16",
            "IPv6Address": ""
        }
    },
    "Options": {},
    "Labels": {
        "com.docker.compose.network": "emulator",
        "com.docker.compose.project": "2234",
        "com.docker.compose.version": "1.27.0"
    }
},
{
    "Name": "2234_main",
    "Id": "b588bb5a545ae0e82f8d13f693d6447024ccf475428e18f31caa7bb4eb9c6102",
    "Created": "2022-02-12T14:23:19.205307729Z",
    "Scope": "local",
    "Driver": "bridge",
    "EnableIPv6": false,
    "IPAM": {
        "Driver": "default",
        "Options": null,
        "Config": [
            {
                "Subnet": "192.168.128.0/20",
                "Gateway": "192.168.128.1"
            }
        ]
    },
    "Internal": false,
    "Attachable": true,
    "Ingress": false,
    "ConfigFrom": {
        "Network": ""
    },
    "ConfigOnly": false,
    "Containers": {
        "0cca77c4db7b0a12d2d61e7cfc2d2357a8dc4214997ec212340331def380c235": {
            "Name": "2234_ServiceA_1",
            "EndpointID": "15d775a2692032800d986390ee2a2b672466c00172dd3cd334fa1f16096ca0b4",
            "MacAddress": "02:42:c0:a8:80:09",
            "IPv4Address": "192.168.128.9/20",
            "IPv6Address": ""
        },
        "0dc64743c4643d972ae5bc9010416880321bb2fde8ad3afd6834fa6d1eaa0cf6": {
            "Name": "2234_ServiceA_1",
            "EndpointID": "134a2b629c98420a80575e622299acd11a03d9cb150aa68c7d71ef942950fa5a",
            "MacAddress": "02:42:c0:a8:80:0e",
            "IPv4Address": "192.168.128.14/20",
            "IPv6Address": ""
        },
        "148494a3f1e0b2d182adc735cace01c91e2f3c365009f476b86503c87b8903fb": {
            "Name": "2234_ServiceA_1",
            "EndpointID": "1ca44d5a3fe1f3d81b9a03eaf89a8cd7fc343e0cdc3bfe27a805de2b6cbfd0bb",
            "MacAddress": "02:42:c0:a8:80:07",
            "IPv4Address": "192.168.128.7/20",
            "IPv6Address": ""
        },
        "1b180c5f62bcd28eb3a28d0c0d682b50080a846f2ccca24a8cf2540f0c95cd6c": {
            "Name": "2234_ServiceA_1",
            "EndpointID": "730db6763b208d4a6e32c1b20bdd5fc56a0f00340f675411001e05e389235a8f",
            "MacAddress": "02:42:c0:a8:80:0f",
            "IPv4Address": "192.168.128.15/20",
            "IPv6Address": ""
        },
        "1c3bf13eee59444abcd225637fb6661fb64bac49d0380063b848f9563bbe08b6": {
            "Name": "2234_ServiceA_1",
            "EndpointID": "585da3c62513f512c6fe2942a4dd8a23c7ff574cc7f8c75ca59ca3e36c369d9e",
            "MacAddress": "02:42:c0:a8:80:0c",
            "IPv4Address": "192.168.128.12/20",
            "IPv6Address": ""
        },
        "23fc36057ded2b07b4d7963b91960c51a088c4c67a41b4993c11a57f735c91c3": {
            "Name": "2234_ServiceA_1",
            "EndpointID": "ff36e613c9a8517caafbc5dc37b1b442fad588f0328d2b5cd1902286fd4ecb84",
            "MacAddress": "02:42:c0:a8:80:0a",
            "IPv4Address": "192.168.128.10/20",
            "IPv6Address": ""
        },
        "2785da15585da3080e6b98b47556b6da191ab8c25b008516654dab0cc06c19e2": {
            "Name": "2234_main_1",
            "EndpointID": "297c57e418c2e079e41a4b9d1dcfcea60bcfad888d3287465d44c5d00761643f",
            "MacAddress": "02:42:c0:a8:80:02",
            "IPv4Address": "192.168.128.2/20",
            "IPv6Address": ""
        },
        "27d50157f4e8664756f36233527892e8c4aa2e0afc723f8ba3e23d4820cbd78d": {
            "Name": "2234_ServiceA_1",
            "EndpointID": "9ca872fb98dd8b9a229cf86975c3e38789679929d7d3e375c292119fdeb4c963",
            "MacAddress": "02:42:c0:a8:80:06",
            "IPv4Address": "192.168.128.6/20",
            "IPv6Address": ""
        },
        "3260d6123a96496dc0b59984ca95d72db7ae688ea8daad92b7a0fbb47ec56207": {
            "Name": "2234_ServiceA_1",
            "EndpointID": "037755d88f02225c41be13206e7c406828ef3dff9767939367af43dd1498dd49",
            "MacAddress": "02:42:c0:a8:80:0b",
            "IPv4Address": "192.168.128.11/20",
            "IPv6Address": ""
        },
        "4b999440f80b9c9e30ced1aba1264f0bed806b30b1a81bcdf3f03f9f4398794e": {
            "Name": "2234_ServiceA_1",
            "EndpointID": "337baff5222025b7d7ea0c5f490a80d1c4f15dbd8b2e5052d0625bb213a407b0",
            "MacAddress": "02:42:c0:a8:80:0d",
            "IPv4Address": "192.168.128.13/20",
            "IPv6Address": ""
        },
        "5d79cb8e56f7a7789f1860bfc0f48077b326736762c2c13238883bac2a5b40d1": {
            "Name": "2234_ConnectToIotService_1",
            "EndpointID": "087108a5226caf371c02ae188d17cd96d464b882ff918fd56d382275e6bb57ab",
            "MacAddress": "02:42:c0:a8:80:08",
            "IPv4Address": "192.168.128.8/20",
            "IPv6Address": ""
        },
        "6524df811e919b3a4f908f286125af45dfd82a3f4aaf9caeb073915bd4bff12e": {
            "Name": "2234_ServiceA_1",
            "EndpointID": "d73cb225903e5817c1cf31dee48d3262719935b1cc514407c833e63595ecf2b8",
            "MacAddress": "02:42:c0:a8:80:05",
            "IPv4Address": "192.168.128.5/20",
            "IPv6Address": ""
        },
        "71c2129a451b66fb9ed25946838f3ecef510cdebc66419c0b060cf15446e606a": {
            "Name": "2234_ServiceA_1",
            "EndpointID": "3806269285d4c60e0de7a3f87ca83c1cb3244578c43905db0e785999e37872d7",
            "MacAddress": "02:42:c0:a8:80:03",
            "IPv4Address": "192.168.128.3/20",
            "IPv6Address": ""
        },
        "df8d304e89af7b8972a62334ca76c5e402f9f530c356b40d8d0d52ca189dee47": {
            "Name": "2234_ServiceA_1",
            "EndpointID": "39f9b5afa2eb6cd5eeaeaaccd03d7594c2b3b0b501399de0d8ea3f9a9e4b92fb",
            "MacAddress": "02:42:c0:a8:80:04",
            "IPv4Address": "192.168.128.4/20",
            "IPv6Address": ""
        }
    },
    "Options": {},
    "Labels": {
        "com.docker.compose.network": "main",
        "com.docker.compose.project": "2234",
        "com.docker.compose.version": "1.27.0"
    }
},
{
    "Name": "2234_nginx",
    "Id": "61d88a21886d9377a8c67b184a4d8a99725ef3b67ec8c2d67dc22de9c271fe96",
    "Created": "2022-02-12T14:23:19.2532414Z",
    "Scope": "local",
    "Driver": "bridge",
    "EnableIPv6": false,
    "IPAM": {
        "Driver": "default",
        "Options": null,
        "Config": [
            {
                "Subnet": "192.168.144.0/20",
                "Gateway": "192.168.144.1"
            }
        ]
    },
    "Internal": false,
    "Attachable": true,
    "Ingress": false,
    "ConfigFrom": {
        "Network": ""
    },
    "ConfigOnly": false,
    "Containers": {
        "5705f37bb200accee2a1a6a23ba818f89172afab4402809f8f1c6de579437983": {
            "Name": "2234_ARAMZLWebAppService_1",
            "EndpointID": "b0ea1b5f04ef6ea46332914032dceea21f98deeb161b2c04759e7ec587d1f588",
            "MacAddress": "02:42:c0:a8:90:03",
            "IPv4Address": "192.168.144.3/20",
            "IPv6Address": ""
        },
        "df8d304e89af7b8972a62334ca76c5e402f9f530c356b40d8d0d52ca189dee47": {
            "Name": "2234_web_gateway_1",
            "EndpointID": "ecfb032cbd8ab650b7e4cd36c6cfc5035b49a8dc934fc49e4e3a0bf49f5437af",
            "MacAddress": "02:42:c0:a8:90:02",
            "IPv4Address": "192.168.144.2/20",
            "IPv6Address": ""
        }
    },
    "Options": {},
    "Labels": {
        "com.docker.compose.network": "nginx",
        "com.docker.compose.project": "2234",
        "com.docker.compose.version": "1.27.0"
    }
},
{
    "Name": "2028970_main",
    "Id": "a2cf265e7afddb0691bf2a2b06391a8df0358538cbcc3ffd63823207a3a859ff",
    "Created": "2022-02-11T21:43:35.086843314Z",
    "Scope": "local",
    "Driver": "bridge",
    "EnableIPv6": false,
    "IPAM": {
        "Driver": "default",
        "Options": null,
        "Config": [
            {
                "Subnet": "192.168.96.0/20",
                "Gateway": "192.168.96.1"
            }
        ]
    },
    "Internal": false,
    "Attachable": true,
    "Ingress": false,
    "ConfigFrom": {
        "Network": ""
    },
    "ConfigOnly": false,
    "Containers": {},
    "Options": {},
    "Labels": {
        "com.docker.compose.network": "main",
        "com.docker.compose.project": "2028970",
        "com.docker.compose.version": "1.27.0"
    }
},
{
    "Name": "2028970_nginx",
    "Id": "3843388542bc33ef8beb7f81cc599d32b534ade592a8945d62a24ea63aac1d69",
    "Created": "2022-02-11T21:43:35.135249579Z",
    "Scope": "local",
    "Driver": "bridge",
    "EnableIPv6": false,
    "IPAM": {
        "Driver": "default",
        "Options": null,
        "Config": [
            {
                "Subnet": "192.168.112.0/20",
                "Gateway": "192.168.112.1"
            }
        ]
    },
    "Internal": false,
    "Attachable": true,
    "Ingress": false,
    "ConfigFrom": {
        "Network": ""
    },
    "ConfigOnly": false,
    "Containers": {},
    "Options": {},
    "Labels": {
        "com.docker.compose.network": "nginx",
        "com.docker.compose.project": "2028970",
        "com.docker.compose.version": "1.27.0"
    }
},
{
    "Name": "bridge",
    "Id": "4fb7977a225db6fa2b8dea7005793a72575cb083b2f997627904a62895cd7f8b",
    "Created": "2021-07-29T16:09:49.572103372Z",
    "Scope": "local",
    "Driver": "bridge",
    "EnableIPv6": false,
    "IPAM": {
        "Driver": "default",
        "Options": null,
        "Config": [
            {
                "Subnet": "172.17.0.0/16",
                "Gateway": "172.17.0.1"
            }
        ]
    },
    "Internal": false,
    "Attachable": false,
    "Ingress": false,
    "ConfigFrom": {
        "Network": ""
    },
    "ConfigOnly": false,
    "Containers": {},
    "Options": {
        "com.docker.network.bridge.default_bridge": "true",
        "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_icc": "true",
        "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_ip_masquerade": "true",
        "com.docker.network.bridge.host_binding_ipv4": "0.0.0.0",
        "com.docker.network.bridge.name": "docker0",
        "com.docker.network.driver.mtu": "1500"
    },
    "Labels": {}
},
{
    "Name": "host",
    "Id": "adc73d076a994102aa472eb367600c8096aa914297158b10d4b25cd8fa50ed0c",
    "Created": "2021-05-11T20:36:17.195375337Z",
    "Scope": "local",
    "Driver": "host",
    "EnableIPv6": false,
    "IPAM": {
        "Driver": "default",
        "Options": null,
        "Config": []
    },
    "Internal": false,
    "Attachable": false,
    "Ingress": false,
    "ConfigFrom": {
        "Network": ""
    },
    "ConfigOnly": false,
    "Containers": {
        "5af2e9b7e09b87ef226e2f79a2d97c9f81148a4265230758949717f2dd525c97": {
            "Name": "2234_IdsService_1",
            "EndpointID": "6ce2fdcb4315fa8368435abaaee1f1c41c4f3a771061992225bb0e49b348e24f",
            "MacAddress": "",
            "IPv4Address": "",
            "IPv6Address": ""
        }
    },
    "Options": {},
    "Labels": {}
},
{
    "Name": "none",
    "Id": "ee93bca5bbc6e27bce0cab8380e11a4c3b95a4cc17aaff50a1665b5dcb8a0ecd",
    "Created": "2021-05-11T20:36:17.184580174Z",
    "Scope": "local",
    "Driver": "null",
    "EnableIPv6": false,
    "IPAM": {
        "Driver": "default",
        "Options": null,
        "Config": []
    },
    "Internal": false,
    "Attachable": false,
    "Ingress": false,
    "ConfigFrom": {
        "Network": ""
    },
    "ConfigOnly": false,
    "Containers": {},
    "Options": {},
    "Labels": {}
}
]
```

Comment: Is your default docker network bridged with the host network? Can you please show your docker networks configuration? (it could be the output of something like `docker network ls | tail -n+2  |  awk '{print $1}' | xargs docker inspect`)

Comment: @madbird hi I have updated the network configuration by running that command. My container that tries to connect to AWS IoT Mqtt endpoint is `2234_ConnectToIotService_1`